# Weird Powershell `Set-AWSCredentials` error with INI file

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-powershell

I'm working on an unattended PowerShell script and want to store AWS credentials the Right Way.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html), I should be able to store credentials in a .ini file like this

*.\myAWSCredentials.ini*

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

[namedProfile]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

and load it into my environment with

`Set-AWSCredentials -ProfilesLocation .\myAWSCredentials.ini`

or

`Set-AWSCredentials -ProfileName namedProfile -ProfilesLocation .\myAWSCredentials.ini`

But I get an error that doesn't make sense— what does PowerShell have to do with an *App.config* file?

> Set-AWSCredentials : Error loading stored credentials, (profile
>   location = '.\myAWSCredentials.ini'). Error: App.config does not
>   contain credentials information. Either add the AWSAccessKey and
>   AWSSecretKey or AWSProfileName. At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AWSCredentials -ProfilesLocation .\myAWSCredentials.ini
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AWSCredentials], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Amazon.PowerShell.Common.SetCredentialsCmdlet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out in investigating this, we have a bug in handling the .ini format file in the latest releases (3.1.31.0 onwards) that I'm fixing now.

If you're not using one of these releases (and I don't think you are based on the message, which was fixed in those releases) then try supplying the full path to the credential file to -ProfilesLocation - it could be that the 'current path' as far as PowerShell is concerned isn't what you think it is when the cmdlet runs (I've run into this with other files I've tried to access for example from my profile).

I'll update further when I've fixed the issue.

Comment: v3.1.33.0 has now been released that fixes the bug I noted (the tools would error out with a 'profile not found' error when using the text-format credential files. Provided .\ is correct for the file location or you pass the full path to the credential file you should be able to load credentials and not encounter the strange app.config message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve Roberts—I've updated and get correct behavior now and better error messages. I was also messing up the keys in the INI file. I will edit my example above so as not to lead anyone down that same path.

Comment: It still requires the full path to the INI file. Not sure why/when but you may want to note in documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass that onto our doc team. I think it's probably safest to always use a full path anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you fully qualify the path it should work....relative paths are evil.

For example use:
Set-AWSCredentials -ProfilesLocation c:\Path\to\file\myAWSCredentials.ini

Answer (score 0):

easily u can store the credentials by following powershell user guide

```
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey xxxxxxx44Hxxxxxxx -SecretKey WVBUyB5ylBWtpxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -StoreAs awskeys
```